# Exporting Python List into csv

Tags: python, csv

So I am trying to create a truth table that I can export out into either a csv or excel format. I am a newbie to Python, so please bear with me if my code is horrible.

I started with this as my code for the truth table after some research:

```
import itertools 
table = list(itertools.product([False, True], repeat=6)) 
print(table)
```

Then I got to this code:

```
import csv
import sys
with open('C:\\blahblah5.csv','w') as fout:
writer = csv.writer(fout, delimiter = ',')
writer.writerows(table)
```

This gets me almost to where I need to be with the truth table in a csv format. However, when I open up the file in excel, there are blank rows inserted between my records.
I tried a tip I found online where I need to change the input type from w to wb, but I get this error when I do:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<pyshell#238>", line 3, in <module>
writer3.writerows(table)
TypeError: 'str' does not support the buffer interface
```

I am not sure where to go from here because I feel like I am so close to getting this into the format I want.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I suspect you're using Python 3.  The way you open files for writing `csv`s changed a little: if you write

```
with open("C:\\blahblah5.csv", "w", newline="") as fout:
```

it should work, producing a file which looks like

```
False,False,False,False,False,False
False,False,False,False,False,True
False,False,False,False,True,False
[etc.]
```

Comment: Perhaps add a link to [the documentation's note about it](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/csv.html#id3).

Answer (score 1):

And if not using python3 you should open the file with [`"wb"`](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/csv.html#csv.writer).

```
import csv

with open('C:\\blahblah5.csv','wb') as fout:
    writer = csv.writer(fout)
    writer.writerows(table)
```